# Handling preprocessor macro in a single header file?

Tags: c++, cmake, macros, preprocessor

In my c++ project, I have some preprocessor macro commands.As an example:

```
#define ENABLE_PHOTO_SENSOR //will be put in three source file (.cc file)

#define SAVE_ROOT_FILE //will be placed 6 source file 

...
```

Should I have to put all these macro commands in a single header file? If I do like this, when I change one of the macro commands(example undef one macro) and compile the program again,  all the source files including those header files are compiled again. If I use separate header file for each macro command, only related source file compiled. But what I want is to control all the macro commands from a single file and when I change a macro command, only the files related to that macro commands are changed.

Finally, I am using cmake to generate make files. Is it possible to change these macro commands in the build directory?If it is how?

Comment: The preprocessor does not know in advance whether any of your macros are used in a source file.  So if you want to avoid recompiling files then you should rethink your program's design.  Personally, I would say that unless compilation time is a massive problem for you, it's better to keep all your options in one place and take the hit on compilation.  Keeping your design simple will probably help you in future.

Comment: Is there any reason for these to be macros?

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd probably just stick both macros into a single header file, include it where needed, and accept the (small) hit on compilation time.   It's only if the impact is significant (e.g.  the total time to recompile dependencies is measured in hours or days, rather than a minute or two) that I'd bother with putting them in separate headers.  Bear in mind that, in practice, header files change much less frequently than source files that include them.   Also, consider finding an alternative to macros

Comment: Thank you for your reply paddy. I use preprocessor for conditional compliation. since there are a few unrelated class,  I prefer to use preprocessor macro. Depending on the user selection, a few class will not be used. Is it possible to handle without preprocessor macro? maybe there is a better way to handle..

Comment: Thank you @peter. I will follow your advice